# How to add multiple/conditional fallbacks (fonts) using fontspec and lualatex?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, bold, cjk

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Note that I don't use emoji in this example,
% but the font for them must be present (not removed).
\begin{luacode*}
luaotfload.add_fallback("FallbackFonts", {% (2)
  "Noto Color Emoji:mode=harf",
  "Noto Sans CJK JP:"
})

luaotfload.add_fallback("FallbackFontsBold", {% (2)
  "Noto Color Emoji:mode=harf",
  "Noto Sans CJK JP Bold:"
})
\end{luacode*}

\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}[
  RawFeature={fallback=FallbackFonts}% (1)
]

\begin{document}

test

\textbf{test}

日本語

\textbf{日本語}

\end{document}
```

If I use FallbackFonts or FallbackFontsBold here (1), then it will print all CJK glyphs either bold or not:

[image: FallbackFonts] [image: FallbackFontsBold]

luatex engine must determine which font to use anyway, right? Then is it possible to make luatex choose which font from fallback (2) must be used for a certain glyph? Like override logic which is already defined (in the engine). Or make use of multiple fallbacks (2) like so:

```latex
...
function set_fallback(font, weight)
  if weight == "bold" then
    font.fallbacks = {"FallbackFontsBold"}
  else
    font.fallbacks = {"FallbackFonts"}
  end
end
...
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}[
  RawFeature={fallback={FallbackFonts, FallbackFontsBold}}% error
  RawFeature={fallback={"FallbackFonts","FallbackFontsBold"}}% same error:
% texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-fallback.lua:81: Unknown fallback table fallbackfonts,fallbackfontsbold.
]
...
```